# Never Seen Star Wars

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

Shortly after [Cueball dodged a bullet](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/never_seen_star_wars.png), he receives an e-mail from Megan. To his misfortune, the topic is once again Star Wars...

> Hi Cueball!
>
> I know you love puzzles and I just got word you're also a Star Wars fan, so guess what I've prepared for you ;) This (imprecise) lightsaber clock hides the name of my favorite Star Wars character. Tell me who it is so I know you're not lying about all this :P
>
> [image]

Cueball does not want to face the horrible consequences of admitting he has never seen Star Wars. Can you help him solve Megan's puzzle and make him look like a Star Wars fan

---

<sub>It might not look like it, but there are 3 steps in this puzzle, so partial answers are welcome.</sub>

Comment: Not enough progress to post even a partial solution, but in case it helps anyone else rot13(Gur qvtvgf 1, 3, 6, 10 naq 12 ner ercynprq ol gur yrggref H, V, T, Z, E, erfcrpgviryl (ybbxf n ybg yvxr vzthe ohg BC vaqvpngrq gung bayl guvf vzntr vf arrqrq.) Naq gur fznyyre grkg arkg gb gur E vf "k2" fb creuncf gurer ner 2 E'f.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Megan's favourite character is

> **Yoda**

The first thing to notice is that

> Like SQLnoob wrote in the comments, the numbers 1, 3, 6, 10 and 12 have been replaced by U, I, G, M and R in the [Aurebesh script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_in_Star_Wars). Reordering these gives IMGUR and reordering the replaced numbers in the same way gives 3, 10, 6, 1, 12.
>
>  Now, there is also **x2** written besides the 12 so taking A1Z26 for the numbers 3, 10, 6, 1, 24 gives **CJFAX**.
>
>  Taking them lowercase brings us to the following imgur link depicting the galaxy map of Star Wars.
>  [image]
>
>  Now, we can overlay the clock with the center of the deep core of the galaxy like this
>  [image]
>
>  Next, we should look for the planets that the clock hands are pointing at. Furthermore, we should look for planets in the same colored regions as the clock hands.
>
>  The hand pointing north points at **Ord Mantell** inside the Mid Rim. The hand pointing south east points at **Denon** inside the Colonies and **Ando** inside the Mid Rim. The hand pointing south points at **Yag'Dhul** inside the Colonies.
>
>  Taking the first letters of these planets and putting them in the correct order gives
>  **YODA**

Comment: Argh, you beat me to it by 2 mins!  I just noticed OP's edit to the puzzle in response to my comment, which gave away the crucial step.  Good job!

Comment: Neat, but do we allow clues stored externally on ephemeral images?

Comment: @smci The image is uploaded to i
stack.imgur, so yes. It is considered self-contained, just like an image directly in the body of a post is fine.

Comment: Stackexchange pays Imgur for the hosting of i.stack.imgur.com. any picture drag+dropped onto stackexchange posts is uploaded there.

Comment: @masterX244 and Lukas: Ah ok, thanks